# Get number of posts per month in data.stackexchange

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data.stackexchange.com

I'm trying to get the total monthly number of posts per month

```
WITH QuestStatsByMonth  AS (
    SELECT  DATEADD (month, DATEDIFF (month, 0, q.CreationDate), 0) AS [Month],
    t.TagName,
    SUM (q.Score)               AS TotalScore,
    q.Id                        AS id

    FROM        Posts           q
    INNER JOIN  PostTags        pt
    ON          q.Id            = pt.PostId
    INNER JOIN  Tags            t
    ON          t.Id            = pt.TagId

    WHERE       q.PostTypeId    = 1
    AND         t.TagName       IN ('perl6')

    GROUP BY    DATEADD (month, DATEDIFF (month, 0, q.CreationDate), 0),
                t.TagName
)
SELECT
q.[Month], q.TagName + ' questions' AS [Tag], COUNT(q.id) AS Qs

FROM        QuestStatsByMonth   q
LEFT JOIN   QuestStatsByMonth   h
ON          h.[Month]           <= q.[Month]
AND         h.TagName           = q.TagName
GROUP BY    q.[Month], q.TagName
ORDER BY    q.[Month], q.TagName
```

But this issues a

> Column 'Posts.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I have tried to make COUNT in the WITH statement, but then the error is somewhere else. Any idea?

Comment: [SEDE Demo2](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/847859)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of these bits:

> ```
> SUM (q.Score)               AS TotalScore,
> ```

and

> ```
> GROUP BY    DATEADD (month, DATEDIFF (month, 0, q.CreationDate), 0),
>             t.TagName
> ```

Within your CTE, you just filter questions. You shouldn't actually group yet if grouping is something you do in your main query. Grouping makes it impossible to select `q.Id`: you asked for one row for each month/tag, but there are generally multiple question IDs in each month/tag. You can just drop `TotalScore` without replacing it because you don't use it anyway.

Comment: This works, but the numbers do not add up [It returns up to thousands of questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/847857/question-count-or-score-growth-over-time-by-tag-comparison), when the total by tag is around 600

Comment: @jjmerelo That's a result of your `LEFT JOIN`, which effectively turns the result into sort of a cumulative sum. I see now that it doesn't even work properly for that. You can take it out (as in Bogdan's answer) since you don't use anything from `h`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `q.id` with agg function:

```
WITH QuestStatsByMonth  AS (
    SELECT DATEADD (month, DATEDIFF (month, 0, q.CreationDate), 0) AS [Month],
    t.TagName,
    SUM (q.Score)               AS TotalScore,
    COUNT(q.Id)                 AS id

    FROM  Posts           q
    JOIN  PostTags        pt
      ON  q.Id            = pt.PostId
    JOIN  Tags            t
      ON  t.Id            = pt.TagId
    WHERE q.PostTypeId    = 1
      AND t.TagName       IN ('perl6')
    GROUP BY    DATEADD (month, DATEDIFF (month, 0, q.CreationDate), 0),
                t.TagName
)
SELECT
  q.[Month], q.TagName + ' questions' AS [Tag],
  SUM(q.id) AS Qs
FROM        QuestStatsByMonth   q
LEFT JOIN   QuestStatsByMonth   h
  ON          h.[Month]           <= q.[Month]
  AND         h.TagName           = q.TagName
GROUP BY    q.[Month], q.TagName
ORDER BY    q.[Month], q.TagName;
```

**[SEDE Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/847859)**

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `LEFT JOIN` part.

```
WITH QuestStatsByMonth  AS (
    SELECT DATEADD (month, DATEDIFF (month, 0, q.CreationDate), 0) AS [Month],
    t.TagName,
    SUM (q.Score)               AS TotalScore,
    COUNT(q.Id)                        AS id

    FROM  Posts           q
    JOIN  PostTags        pt
      ON  q.Id            = pt.PostId
    JOIN  Tags            t
      ON  t.Id            = pt.TagId
    WHERE q.PostTypeId    = 1
      AND t.TagName       IN ('perl6')
    GROUP BY    DATEADD (month, DATEDIFF (month, 0, q.CreationDate), 0),
                t.TagName
)
SELECT
  q.[Month], q.TagName + ' questions' AS [Tag],
  COUNT(q.id) AS Qs
FROM        QuestStatsByMonth   q
GROUP BY    q.[Month], q.TagName
ORDER BY    q.[Month], q.TagName
```

Looks like what you are asking.